# Adding active class to dynamically appended elements isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I've created a fixed horizontal navigation bar at the top of the page. What I want to do is to change the background color of the menu item corresponding to the current page, but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried looking for other similar questions, but none of the solutions fixed my problem.

First of all, I'm dynamically adding the navigation bar on each page once it loads. That's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // 'header' is the div wrapping the navbar
    $('#header').html(
        "<ul id='menu'>" +
        "<li><a href='rooms.php'>Rooms</a></li>" +
        "<li><a href='gallery.php'>Gallery</a></li>" +
        "<li><a href='reviews.php'>Reviews</a></li>" +
        "<li><a href='contact.php'>Contact Us</a></li>" +
        "</ul>"
    );
});
```

And here's the function I wrote that's supposed to set menu items as 'active':

```
$('#menu li').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

I think this is being caused by the fact that the links are indeed being set as 'active', but since the navigation bar is dynamically created, it's "overriding" the changes (am I right?). The problem is that I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you navigate away, the class will not stick on the next page load. You would need to run code to figure what the active page is and select it.

Comment: Just make sure the second part of the code is also within the document.ready function.